Stored procedure not executing in parallel on Azure SQL Server
I need to delete a lot of users and users data, and in hangfire I created a job that enqueues 5 jobs that each execute stored procedure and passes Ids for deletion(batches of 100):
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
     var batch = peopleForCleanup.Skip(batchSize * i).Take(batchSize).ToList();
     backgroundJobClient.Enqueue(() => PeopleCleanupAsync(batch));
     }

This is the code that is calling stored procedure:
    await using (var con = new SqlConnection(appConString))
                        await using (var cmd = new SqlCommand())
                        {
                            cmd.Connection = con;
                            await con.OpenAsync();
                            cmd.CommandTimeout = 3600; // 30min
                            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                            cmd.CommandText = "DeletePersonData";
                            // Define TVP parameter
                            var tvpParam = new SqlParameter("@PersonIds", SqlDbType.Structured)
                            {
                                TypeName = "dbo.PersonIdTableType",
                                Value = personIdTable
                            };
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(tvpParam);
                            var errorParam = new SqlParameter("@Errors", SqlDbType.NVarChar, int.MaxValue)
                            {
                                Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
                            };
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(errorParam);
                            Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                            await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
                            sw.Stop();
                            Console.WriteLine("Task = " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + " TIME == " + sw.Elapsed.ToString());
                            errors = Convert.ToString(errorParam.Value);
                            Console.WriteLine("Errors: " + errors);
                            _logger.LogInformation("DeletePersonData stored procedure executed in " + sw.Elapsed.ToString()); 
}

So I have 5 parallel jobs running and calling this stored procedure to delete data, but for some reason procedures are being executed one by one.
I can confirm that behaviour by running this script where I see blockings:
WITH cteBL (session_id, blocking_these) AS
(SELECT s.session_id, blocking_these = x.blocking_these FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions s
CROSS APPLY    (SELECT isnull(convert(varchar(6), er.session_id),'') + ', '
                FROM sys.dm_exec_requests as er
                WHERE er.blocking_session_id = isnull(s.session_id ,0)
                AND er.blocking_session_id <> 0
                FOR XML PATH('') ) AS x (blocking_these)
)
SELECT s.session_id, blocked_by = r.blocking_session_id, bl.blocking_these
, batch_text = t.text, input_buffer = ib.event_info, *
FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions s
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.dm_exec_requests r on r.session_id = s.session_id
INNER JOIN cteBL as bl on s.session_id = bl.session_id
OUTER APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text (r.sql_handle) t
OUTER APPLY sys.dm_exec_input_buffer(s.session_id, NULL) AS ib
WHERE blocking_these is not null or r.blocking_session_id > 0
ORDER BY len(bl.blocking_these) desc, r.blocking_session_id desc, r.session_id;

I have also try to execute stored procedure with: await _appContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync("EXEC DeletePersonData @PersonIds, @Errors OUT", new[] { tvpParam, errorParam }); but no luck - same result.
I also put MultipleActiveResultSets=True in connection string, and I checked Azure SQL database select [value] from sys.database_scoped_configurations where name = 'MAXDOP' is 8 - which I think is enough for this. I don't know what am I doing wrong and how can I speed this up.
Thanks

It appears you are running into the issue described here on option 3: "To run multiple deletes concurrently, you need a way to partition them so each parallel delete runs on its own set of keys and doesn't block with the others.". Apparently your question here is more database-related than it is application.

To get these to not interfere with each other, the DELETE would have to join on a section of the primary key (so make sure your TVP is indexed) but different from any other DELETE, and no other indexes could be present on the table. If there are other indexes then those indexes need locking, and that index is going to be in a completely different order than the primary key, so the locking will interfere (and may even deadlock). Also locking for DML usually locks at least at page level, and sometimes escalates to table level. This is why parallelizing is normally a complete waste of time.

So better to just loop deletion of 4999 rows at a time until you're done. Or copy the data you do want to keep to a new table, truncate the original and SWITCH it in. Also, MultipleActiveResultSets=True is a bad idea as it slows down the connection, it's only necessary for Select N+1 queries, which are themselves a bad idea.
